# Объект в Unity летит вверх, хотя должен падать

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Неустойчивый объект стоит на платформе и при нажатии *Play* должен падать, а он летит вверх. Use gravity включено. На скрине - inspector этого объекта. Скрипта у него нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть дело?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно угадать ваш код?

Comment: У вас монитор вверх ногами стоит. Переверните его.

Comment: Anton Nikolaev, вы о чём?

Comment: [Оно](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/customizing-or-disabling-global-gravity-in-unity)?